# Error installing containerd.io_1.6.9-1_amd64.deb on docker container

Tags: linux, docker, deb

I'm trying to build a Docker container with the following commands in Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6.2
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install make
RUN pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
RUN python -m pip install -r model-requirements.txt --python-version 3.6 --no-deps --target python6_pakages
# Installing docker-ce
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common -y --force-yes
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg --force-yes
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
RUN curl -O https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/buster/pool/stable/amd64/containerd.io_1.6.9-1_amd64.deb   
RUN apt install ./containerd.io_1.6.9-1_amd64.deb   
RUN apt-cache policy docker-ce
RUN apt-cache search docker-ce
RUN apt install docker-ce -y
RUN apt-get install -y cron vim iputils-ping curl g++ unixodbc-dev gnupg supervisor
```

The problem us that when building process reaches the line `RUN apt install ./containerd.io_1.6.9-1_amd64.deb`  I get errors like the following:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. I've double-checked the download URL and the package is successfully downloaded every time. Can you help me with this error?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Do you need to `dpkg --install` the separate `*.deb` file; or having added a Docker APT repository, can you `apt-get install containerd.io` without separately downloading it?

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi david! Thanks for the tip. I did'nt use apt because apt doesn't support this pakage. dpkg also didn't work :(